# How do you design a table with 3 compound primary keys

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with columns Form, Appraiser, date and Level

A form can never have same appraisers, and a form can never have same Levels.

I tried to make primary key(Form,appraiser) and primary key(Form,level) but it says that form has multiple primary keys

If i put primary key(form,appraiser,level) people can just insert the same form and appraiser twice but just with a different level and that violates my rules.

```
       |Form|Appraiser|Level|
         1       A       1
         1       B       2
         1       C       3
         2       A       1
         2       B       2
         2       C       3
```

Comment: Seems like you want unique constraints rather than primary keys.

Comment: @jarlh oh ok thank you that worked, is there any advantage to using compound primary keys over compound unique keys?

Comment: @jarlh But if two different forms could have the _same_ appraiser or level, then a unique constraint by itself would not work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi sorry i think i have a bit of misunderstanding on my question, its actually an appraiser can never have the same level in one single form, so what i really wanted to put was primarykey(Form,appraiser) and primary key(form,appraiser,level)

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added, i omitted the date out. So basically a form have appraisers of different levels, the level determine if they are the first, second or third appraiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (form INTEGER, appraiser TEXT, level INTEGER, UNIQUE(form,appraiser), UNIQUE(form,level));
```

e.g. Using the following

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (form INTEGER, appraiser TEXT, level INTEGER, UNIQUE(form,appraiser), UNIQUE(form,level));
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
                (1,'A',1),(1,'B',2),(1,'C',3),
                (2,'A',1),(2,'B',2),(2,'C',3)
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO mytable VALUES (1,'A',4);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO mytable values (1,'Z',1);
```

The results are :-

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
                (1,'A',1),(1,'B',2),(1,'C',3),
                (2,'A',1),(2,'B',2),(2,'C',3)
> Affected rows: 6
> Time: 0.083s
```

- all added

but

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO mytable VALUES (1,'A',4)
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s
```

- not added as A has already apprasied form 1.

and also

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO mytable values (1,'Z',1)
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s
```

- not added as for 1 has already been appraised at level 1

Answer (score 1):

We can try using two junction tables here:

```
CREATE TABLE form_appraiser (
    form_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    appraiser_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (form_id, appraiser_id)
);

CREATE TABLE form_level (
    form_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    level_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (form_id, level_id)
);
```

Each of these two tables would ensure that a given form can only be associated with a single appraiser or level.

Then, maintain a third table `forms` containing one record for each unique form.  If you have the additional requirement that a given form can only have one appraiser or level, then add a unique constraint on the form, on one/both of the junction tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the unique constraint as a column identifier.

like

appraiser VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
form       VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
level      VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,

In this case non of the values repeats. If you want a combination of values not to repeat you can use
 UNIQUE(form, level)
This means you cannot have a form of the same level repeating.